# stop solr search after timeout

Tags: jakarta-ee, solr, lucene

I'm using solr and search on distributed lucene indices over network. I send queries from arbiter to searchers (solr) and then get the result.

Some of queries take a lot of time (more than a minute) to be finished on searchers and slow down the search for other queries.

How can I set a timeout for solr so that if a query takes more than a specified time, it cancels the search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setTimeAllowed function does it!

```
public SolrQuery setTimeAllowed(Integer milliseconds)
```

Set the maximum time allowed for this query. If the query takes more time than the specified milliseconds, a timeout occurs and partial (or no) results may be returned. If given Integer is null, then this parameter is removed from the request

```
Parameters:  
milliseconds - the time in milliseconds allowed for this query
```

Comment: Cool .. seems a new add. Also the partial results seems to be odd. But as long as it cut a request its nice.